# Getting 2g speeds on hyper-v VM through a 10g nic

Tags: nic, windows-server-2019, truenas, 10gbethernet, iperf

I'm testing my speeds using IPERF as I've recently installed a 10G cisco switch and intel 10g NIC's on some servers to communicate with a nas server.

I noticed my reads and write were awful so I've tested the NIC's themselves and on the host machine (windows server 2019) when testing the nic against itself I'm getting correct 10G speed.

When I test from a VM inside the host to the host both running Windows Server 2019 my speeds drop to +- 2g.

The NIC has 2 interfaces I'm using 1 for the HOST the other in a External Switch to the VM. Not sure why my speed is so degraded?

Comment: SR-IOV is enabled?

Comment: @Berndinox SR-IOV is enabled on the NIC properties on the Host Machine, on the VM's adapter properties that's not an option in the list. I did notice that Jumbo Packets was disabled on the VM, not sure if that makes any difference?